# Как найти первую пустую ячейку в строке

Tags: excel, vba

Как найти первую пустую ячейку в строке, начиная с колонки I3.
Поиск будет происходить только в первой строке.

Comment: Уточните, какую ячейку: в конце данных или пустую среди данных? Опишите подробнее вопрос.

Comment: Пустая ячейка среди данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lClmn As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lClmn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```

В переменную запишется крайняя справа пустая ячейка в строке 1

Среди данных пустоту можно найти с помощью цикла:

```
Sub FindEmpty()
Dim lClmn As Long, j As Long
    lClmn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 ' первый пустой после данных в строке 1
    If lClmn < 9 Then Exit Sub

    For j = 9 To lClmn ' начало поиска со столбца I
        If Cells(1, j).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next j

    MsgBox j ' сообщение с номером столбца
End Sub
```

Если пустых ячеек среди данных нет, в сообщении укажется номер первого столбца после диапазона данных

Comment: .Cells здесь разве нужна точка перед Cells и Columns?

Comment: Точка ставится, если указан родитель. Без родителя ссылки относятся к активному листу

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rows(1).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1).Select
```